# Problem with code to export a file from R into CSV

Tags: r

I have successfully performed a matching of two groups using Matchit. The list of matched people is called `m.data1` and I am trying to export it to a CSV file on my Mac. I used the following code:

```
write.csv(m.data1,'t.csv')
```

This worked well a few days ago but now the file isn't exported (although there is no error message).

I tried `getwd()` and which was "/Users/myname" so then I tried the following:

`write.csv(m.data1,file= "/Users/myname/desktop/t.csv")` but this also doesn't export a file.

I would really appreciate some advice!

Comment: If it gives no error, its exporting it somewhere... if your `getwd()` returns "Users/myname", try to look for it there or (if on windows) try to do a system search for t.csv

Comment: If it worked before, then boski is right. On mac you could also use cmd+spacebar to search you mac. You may need to give it a more unique name but you should be able to find where R is exporting it.